# Internet Explorer to Google Chrome in wapache

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Hi i have a project which is developed with Google Chrome browser and when i try implementing with wapache everything works except for the css and javascript errors which blocks many functionality. Is there any possibilities for wapache to use chrome browser instead of internet explorer..

Answer (score 2):

there is alternative project that implements MSIE OR google chrome...
it's [phpdesktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) on google code.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Wapache needs Internet Explorere and I'm not aware of any alternative.